# "Peer closed connection" from all nodeos mainnet p2p-peer-addresses

Tags: nodeos

I'm trying setup a non producing EOS mainnet node but I'm getting "Peer closed connection" from all peers (Using this list of peers: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CryptoLions/EOS-MainNet/master/genesis.json)

I'm running:

```
nodeos --disable-replay-opts --delete-all-blocks
```

Getting:

```
...
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.775 net-5     net_plugin.cpp:2350           operator()           ] Peer closed connection
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.775 net-5     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: boot.eostitan.com:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.775 net-5     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'boot.eostitan.com:9876', boot.eostitan.com:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.794 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:1070           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 1 to seed1.greymass.com:9876, lib 1, head 1, id bcf2f448225d0996
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.797 net-5     net_plugin.cpp:1070           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 1 to seed2.greymass.com:9876, lib 1, head 1, id bcf2f448225d0996
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.797 net-7     net_plugin.cpp:2320           operator()           ] incoming message length unexpected (1347703880)
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.797 net-7     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: fullnode.eoslaomao.com:443
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.797 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:1070           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 1 to 18.234.6.119:80, lib 1, head 1, id bcf2f448225d0996
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.798 net-4     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'fullnode.eoslaomao.com:443', fullnode.eoslaomao.com:443
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.806 net-3     net_plugin.cpp:1070           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 1 to p2p.eosdetroit.io:3018, lib 1, head 1, id bcf2f448225d0996
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.806 net-6     net_plugin.cpp:2350           operator()           ] Peer closed connection
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.806 net-6     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: bp.eosbeijing.one:8080
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.806 net-6     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'bp.eosbeijing.one:8080', bp.eosbeijing.one:8080
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.811 net-5     net_plugin.cpp:1070           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 1 to node1.eoscannon.io:59876, lib 1, head 1, id bcf2f448225d0996
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.824 net-3     net_plugin.cpp:2350           operator()           ] Peer closed connection
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.824 net-3     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: api-full2.eoseoul.io:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.825 net-3     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'api-full2.eoseoul.io:9876', api-full2.eoseoul.io:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.828 net-6     net_plugin.cpp:2350           operator()           ] Peer closed connection
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.828 net-6     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: bp.cryptolions.io:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.828 net-4     net_plugin.cpp:2350           operator()           ] Peer closed connection
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.828 net-4     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: api-full1.eoseoul.io:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.828 net-6     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'bp.cryptolions.io:9876', bp.cryptolions.io:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.828 net-4     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'api-full1.eoseoul.io:9876', api-full1.eoseoul.io:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.854 net-1     net_plugin.cpp:2350           operator()           ] Peer closed connection
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.854 net-1     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: p2p.eos.cryptolions.io:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.854 net-1     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'p2p.eos.cryptolions.io:9876', p2p.eos.cryptolions.io:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.939 net-6     net_plugin.cpp:2350           operator()           ] Peer closed connection
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.939 net-6     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: seed1.greymass.com:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.939 net-6     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'seed1.greymass.com:9876', seed1.greymass.com:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.945 net-4     net_plugin.cpp:2350           operator()           ] Peer closed connection
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.945 net-4     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: seed2.greymass.com:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.945 net-4     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'seed2.greymass.com:9876', seed2.greymass.com:9876
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.949 net-5     net_plugin.cpp:2320           operator()           ] incoming message length unexpected (1347703880)
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.949 net-5     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: 18.234.6.119:80
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.949 net-5     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing '18.234.6.119:80', 18.234.6.119:80
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.951 net-7     net_plugin.cpp:1070           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 1 to peer1.mainnet.helloeos.com.cn:80, lib 1, head 1, id bcf2f448225d0996
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.951 net-2     net_plugin.cpp:1070           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 1 to peer2.mainnet.helloeos.com.cn:80, lib 1, head 1, id bcf2f448225d0996
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.962 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:2350           operator()           ] Peer closed connection
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.962 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: publicnode.cypherglass.com:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.962 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'publicnode.cypherglass.com:9876', publicnode.cypherglass.com:9876
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.967 net-4     net_plugin.cpp:2350           operator()           ] Peer closed connection
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.967 net-4     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: p2p.eosdetroit.io:3018
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.967 net-6     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'p2p.eosdetroit.io:3018', p2p.eosdetroit.io:3018
info  2020-06-24T10:38:55.970 net-4     net_plugin.cpp:2350           operator()           ] Peer closed connection
error 2020-06-24T10:38:55.970 net-4     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: node1.eoscannon.io:
```

Using nodeos v2.0.6.
genesis.json taken from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CryptoLions/EOS-MainNet/master/genesis.json
My config.ini (Based on https://docs.liquidapps.io/en/v2.0/dsps/eosio-node.html):

```
agent-name = "DSP"
http-server-address = 0.0.0.0:8888
p2p-listen-endpoint = 0.0.0.0:9876
blocks-dir = "blocks"
abi-serializer-max-time-ms = 3000
max-transaction-time = 150000
wasm-runtime = eos-vm
eos-vm-oc-enable = true
reversible-blocks-db-size-mb = 1024
contracts-console = true
p2p-max-nodes-per-host = 1
allowed-connection = any
max-clients = 100
sync-fetch-span = 500
connection-cleanup-period = 30
http-validate-host = false
access-control-allow-origin = *
access-control-allow-headers = *
access-control-allow-credentials = false
verbose-http-errors = true
http-threads=8
net-threads=8
chain-threads=8
eos-vm-oc-compile-threads=2
trace-history-debug-mode = true
trace-history = true
plugin = eosio::producer_plugin
plugin = eosio::chain_plugin
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::net_plugin
plugin = eosio::state_history_plugin
state-history-endpoint = 0.0.0.0:8887
chain-state-db-size-mb = 16384
p2p-peer-address = 18.234.6.119:80
p2p-peer-address = api-full1.eoseoul.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = api-full2.eoseoul.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = boot.eostitan.com:9876
p2p-peer-address = bp.cryptolions.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = bp.eosbeijing.one:8080
p2p-peer-address = br.eosrio.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = eos-seed-de.privex.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = fullnode.eoslaomao.com:443
p2p-peer-address = mainnet.eoscalgary.io:5222
p2p-peer-address = node.eosflare.io:1883
p2p-peer-address = node1.eoscannon.io:59876
p2p-peer-address = p2p.eosdetroit.io:3018
p2p-peer-address = p2p.genereos.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = p2p.meet.one:9876
p2p-peer-address = peer.eosn.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = peer.main.alohaeos.com:9876
p2p-peer-address = peer1.mainnet.helloeos.com.cn:80
p2p-peer-address = peer2.mainnet.helloeos.com.cn:80
p2p-peer-address = publicnode.cypherglass.com:9876
p2p-peer-address = seed1.greymass.com:9876
p2p-peer-address = seed2.greymass.com:9876
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using endpoints from https://validate.eosnation.io/eos/reports/config.html solved the issue.